# mosaic chart coloring, scaling and order

Tags: r, mosaic-plot

I am very new to R and just did my first chart:

[View Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tgsB.jpg)

Could you help me understand how I can change the order of the x axis and apply coloring to the different pieces of the mosaic chart?
I would also like to reduce the spacing between the pieces (linebreaks for text?), remove the black borders and avoid the heading to overlap.

Many thanks for any help! I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to specify the levels of your factor in the order you want.

To know more [visit](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~ihaka/120/Lectures/lecture17.pdf)